# About NSNumber numberWithDouble

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
double test1 = 5.58f;

NSString *test2 = @"5.58";

NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:test1]);

NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[test2 doubleValue]]);
```

Output:

> 5.579999923706055
>
> 5.58

Why the convert is difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably due to the fact that 5.58f is a `float`, not a `double`.

Comment: How to write a double literal?

Comment: `5.58l` is a long double, not a double.  A double is just `5.58` no suffix.